# jqGrid show more rows than the specified rowNum value

Tags: jqgrid, rownum

Suppose i need to send parameter "rows" : 10 to server for pagination which is sent by rowNum value in jqGrid but server gives me more than 10 rows lets say 20. Now i need to display 20 rows in one page instead of 10 but because of rowNum set to 10 my table shows 10 rows only. How to display 20 rows after server response?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("#list").jqGrid({
              url: "/show_stock.json",
              mtype: "GET",
              styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
              datatype: "json",
              colModel: [
                  { label: 'Product', name: 'uiproduct_id', key: true, width: 440, formatter: function productFormatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
                      {
                        return '<div> <img src="http://limeroad-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/uiproducts/' +
                                rowObject.uiproduct_id + '/tn_0-' + rowObject.fileidn + '.jpg"/>' + rowObject.lrName +
                                "<div>"+ "Brand: " + rowObject.brand_name + "</div><div>" + "UPID: " + cellvalue +
                                "</div></div>";
                      },
                                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm) {
                                            var attr = rawObject.attr[cm.name], result;
                                            if (attr.rowspan) {
                                                result = ' rowspan=' + '"' + attr.rowspan + '"';
                                            } else if (attr.display) {
                                                result = ' style="display:' + attr.display + '"';
                                            }
                                            return result;
                                        }
                  },
                  { label: ' VendorStyle Code', name: 'vendor_style_code', width: 200, align: 'center', formatter: function styleCodeFormatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject )
                    {
                      return cellvalue + " (" + rowObject.size + ")";
                    }
                  },
                  { label: 'MRP', name: 'mrp', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                  { label: 'Selling Price', name: 'selling_price', defval: '145', width: 150, align: 'center', formatter: function sellingPriceFormatter( cellvalue, options, rowObject)
                    {
                        return rowObject.mrp - (rowObject.discount * rowObject.mrp / 100);
                    }
                  },
                  { label: 'Discount', name: 'discount', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                  { label:'Stock', name: 'quantity', width: 150, align: 'center', editable: true}
              ],
              width: 780,
              height: 400,
              pager: '#mypager',
              viewrecords: true,
              rowNum:10,
              rowList:[10,20,30],
              gridview: true,
              viewrecords: true,
              cellEdit: true,
              cellsubmit: 'remote',
              cellurl: '/update_stock.json',
              afterSubmitCell: function (serverStatus, rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                  var response = trim(serverStatus.responseText);
                  if (response != 'ok') {
                      return [true,""];
                  } else {
                      return [false,response];
                  }
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Is `20` the **total** number of pages? I don't full understand why jqGrid should accept the wrong answer from the server. Let us you go in the restaurant and order a glass of wine and one bring you get a bottle of wine (or two glasses of wine) instead. What you would do in the case? Just get all what one brought you or to try to get exactly what your order? I just try to imagine whether the situation which you describe is realistic or the server just is buggy, it process the request in the wrong way and the server code have to be fixed.

Comment: 20 is the no of rows sent by server for one pagination request. No of rows sent is dynamic.

Comment: You need to change `rowNum:10` to `rowNum:20` because the value of `rowNum` will be sent to the server as `rows` parameter.

Comment: that was the problem.... i need to send 10 only to server. Anyways thanks. i solved it by little bit more digging. i used beforeProcessing function and added this line(withous quotes) "$(this).setGridParams({rowNum: 20}).trigger("reloadGrid");" over there. :)

Comment: You are welcome! You should not set static value 20 dynamically if you already use the static value `10` directly in the grid `rowNum: 10`. It's better just change the value of `rowNum` to 20. By the way 20 is the **default** value for `rowNum` (see  the value from the column "Default" in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)), so you can just remove `rowNum: 10` to send the value 20.

Comment: That was just an example. I am setting it like this
beforeProcessing: function(data, status, xhr) {
                      var a = data.aval;
                      $(this).setGridParam({rowNum: a}).trigger("reloadGrid");
              }
where value of aval is set in server response i.e. no of records server is sending corresponding to value 10

Comment: If you want to display *all* rows then you can set just large enough value for `rowNum`. For example if you have 73 rows in the database, but you use `rowNum: 1000` then all 73 rows (one page with up to 1000 rows) will be returned from the server. The user will see no difference between the settings `rowNum: 1000` and `rowNum: 73`.

Comment: I tried that also.... But some bugginess happened with pagination... It was setting viewrecords numbers to a large value too....